# Getting up to speed on modern PC construction

Tags: computer-building

The last time I built a PC the tricky parts were knowing the difference between ISA, VLB, and PCI cards; juggling IRQs; and getting IDE master/slave right. Now I'm helping my stepson build a gaming PC and I've realised that PC internals have changed a *lot* since then. Multiple fans, thermal paste, dual-channel RAM configurations, a bizarre array of power supply connectors - it's a different world.

I am looking for a *concise* resource for boning up on PC construction.  Not a whole hardware enthusiast website, but a book or series of articles which covers current hardware technology, what plugs in where, common gotchas, how to know if I'm managing heat effectively, that sort of thing. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some links to help you out:

- [How to build a PC - Every step explained | Maximum PC](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/features/video_how_build_pc_ever_step_explained)
- [Tom's Hardware - Step by step guide to building a PC](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/274745-31-step-step-guide-building)
- [Tom's Hardware: Homebuilt PC buying guide](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/273518-31-homebuilt-buying-guide)
- [PC Config/buy list - ( More from an Indian POV but some good tips nonetheless)](http://www.chip.in/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=38500)