# How do I choose hardware for a gaming machine, and which components are the most important ones?

Tags: computer-building

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I know what hardware to buy to meet my needs?](https://superuser.com/questions/297274/how-do-i-know-what-hardware-to-buy-to-meet-my-needs)

I am looking into building a gaming computer from scratch.  I have a certain knowledge of what I will need, but I want to get a better understanding of what is really necessary for as flawless a gaming rig as possible on a budget.

What I know is that I need a powerful graphics card and CPU, and for the most part, not much else, as games dont require a ton of RAM, Hard Drive space, etc.  What I don't know is what constitutes a "powerful" graphics card and CPU.

Basically what I need is for someone to explain what the different specs of computer components (mostly CPU, graphics card, and motherboard) mean, and which ones are important to a good gaming computer.

Also, on a similar note, I am not sure how to choose a power supply that will support all the components that I ultimately buy.  Is there a tool out there that I can use for this?

Comment: Whatever happens to be most expensive at the time of purchase.

Comment: It's not a particularly bad question – given a good answer, that is. Isn't that what we encourage? Questions that help people help themselves (like: How do I find out what constitutes a good graphics card? How do I choose a power supply that supports all components?). It's not even a specific buying recommendation.

Comment: This is what I had in mind when asking the question.  a few months ago I asked a question regarding a specific build and whether or not it was a good one, which in retrospect I realize is not a constructive question.  This I thought would be able to help people in the future, as 'what makes a graphics card good' will still be true in a few years, whereas 'is this a good graphics card' will not.

Comment: I think that the question is overly broad as it is and there would be too much wiggle room for a long protracted discussion.

Comment: My thought was that it could be answered with a simple link to a page that explains different components and what they mean.  I haven't been able to find anything like that.

Comment: It still looks like any concrete advise will be outdated too quickly to be of use on this site. And for what's left, what's the difference to our regular [computer components](http://superuser.com/questions/297274/how-do-i-know-what-hardware-to-buy-to-meet-my-needs) question?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/74246/getting-up-to-speed-on-modern-pc-construction http://superuser.com/questions/297766/how-do-we-assemble-a-computer-properly http://superuser.com/questions/275194/what-should-a-person-know-before-assembling-their-first-computer http://superuser.com/questions/297274/how-do-i-know-what-hardware-to-buy-to-meet-my-needs http://superuser.com/questions/9946/how-to-choose-a-ups-calculate-power-for-a-new-pc

Comment: @DanielBeck I forgot this, but isn't there a difference when talking about a gaming machine? [Requested to reopen](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3716/request-to-reopen-question-358637-hardware-for-a-gaming-pc), I don't see how it's off-topic. At least close it as a duplicate.